# I can't find html tag suggestion box like notepad++, on sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I can't find html tag suggestion box like *Notepad++*, on **Sublime Text 3**.
In *Notepad++* we can find `html tag suggestion` by writing some words.
But I can't find this html suggestion box on **Sublime Text 3**

[image]

Comment: Do you mean HTML snippets? Or auto complete of common html tags? Or auto-closing html tags? What are the `tag suggestion box` in Notepad++?

Comment: that's mean "html tag suggestion box". If i write "h", In the suggestion box I can see h1 or h2 or header or anythings

Comment: That's doesn't make it much clearer to me unfortunately

Comment: Look through the packages to find what you're looking for. A good start would be here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/All%20Autocomplete

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/auto_complete.html

Comment: yeah, I have tried

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ta62x5

Comment: From the link I sent: `Manually Showing Completions
Pressing Ctrl+Space will show the completion popup if it's not currently showing. If it is showing, it'll select the next item.`

Comment: Autocomplete of HTML tags in Sublime is only provided in HTML files; it also requires you to enter the `<` character first; i.e. in an HTML file, `<h` will open the autocomplete for all tags that start with `h`.

Comment: I think the [`Emmet`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) package will help you. You'll need to get used to writing HTML in a somewhat different way, but once you do it's a huge timesaver.